# git-remote-codecommit with temporary credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, aws-codecommit

I am logging as a IAM user which can switch to a Admin role. The user belongs to a UserGroup and the group has the permission to switch to a Admin role. There are no direct attachment of action policies anywhere.

I have configured my AWS CLI with the following.

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1
output = json

[profile parthiva]
aws_access_key_id = <key>
aws_secret_access_key = <secret>

[profile admin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456:role/AdminAccess
source_profile = parthiva
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::123456:mfa/s.parthiva
```

The role Admin looks like this.

```
  RoleAdmin:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${DevAccountId}:root'
            Condition:
              Bool:
                aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent: true
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'              
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
      RoleName: AdminAccess
```

Whenever I do the CLI actions such as `aws s3 ls --profile admin`, it is asking for a MFA token and upon entering the value, the command is successful.

But I could not use this configuration for using CodeCommit HTTPS (GRC). The following is the error

```
parthiva@Parthiva-PC:~$ git clone codecommit::eu-central-1://test-repo
Cloning into 'test-repo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/test-repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

To me, it looks like this codecommit command while using the CLI in the background, is not taking up the profile admin.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, as you have set the default region set as `eu-central-1`, so you can simply run:

```
git clone codecommit://test-repo test-repo
```

To clone a repository in a different AWS Region than the one configured in your profile, you need to include the AWS Region name. For example:

```
git clone codecommit::ap-northeast-1://test-repo test-repo
```

To clone the same repository using a profile named `admin`, you can try something like this:

```
git clone codecommit://admin@test-repo test-repo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently I mislooked something in the configuration